# How to achieve Incremental Encryption with BouncyCastle PGP Utilities in Java?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pgp

```
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] clearData, PGPPublicKey encKey,
        String fileName,boolean withIntegrityCheck, boolean armor)
        throws IOException, PGPException, NoSuchProviderException {
    if (fileName == null) {
        fileName = PGPLiteralData.CONSOLE;
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream encOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    OutputStream out = encOut;
    if (armor) {
        out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    PGPCompressedDataGenerator comData = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(
            PGPCompressedDataGenerator.ZIP);
    OutputStream cos = comData.open(bOut); // open it with the final
    // destination
    PGPLiteralDataGenerator lData = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator();

    // we want to generate compressed data. This might be a user option
    // later,
    // in which case we would pass in bOut.
    OutputStream pOut = lData.open(cos, // the compressed output stream
            PGPLiteralData.BINARY, fileName, // "filename" to store
            clearData.length, // length of clear data
            new Date() // current time
            );
    pOut.write(clearData);

    lData.close();
    comData.close();

    PGPEncryptedDataGenerator cPk = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(new BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTags.AES_192).setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom()));


    cPk.addMethod(new BcPublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(encKey));

    byte[] bytes = bOut.toByteArray();

    OutputStream cOut = cPk.open(out, bytes.length);

    cOut.write(bytes); // obtain the actual bytes from the compressed stream

    cOut.close();

    out.close();

    return encOut.toByteArray();
}
```

Here's a small prototype test class to use that method :

```
 PGPPublicKey pubKey = PGPEncryptionTools.readPublicKeyFromCol(new FileInputStream(appProp.getKeyFileName()));

        byte[] encryptbytes = PGPEncryptionTools.encrypt("\nthis is some test text".getBytes(), pubKey, null, true, false);
        byte[] encryptbytes2 = PGPEncryptionTools.encrypt("\nmore test text".getBytes(), pubKey, null, true, false);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/me/workspace/workspace/spring-batch-project/resources/encryptedfile.gpg");
        fos.write(encryptbytes);
        fos.write(encryptbytes2);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
```

So this creates `encryptedfile.gpg`, but when I go to GnuPG to decrypt the file, it works but it only outputs the first line "this is some test text".

**How can I modify this code to be able to encrypt both lines and have GnuPG decrypt them?**

Above code I am using to decrypt the code.

```
public static void decryptFile(
        InputStream in,
        InputStream keyIn,
        char[] passwd,
        String defaultFileName)
        throws IOException, NoSuchProviderException {
    in = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in);

    try {
        JcaPGPObjectFactory pgpF = new JcaPGPObjectFactory(in);
        PGPEncryptedDataList enc;

        Object o = pgpF.nextObject();
        //
        // the first object might be a PGP marker packet.
        //
        if (o instanceof PGPEncryptedDataList) {
            enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) o;
        } else {
            enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) pgpF.nextObject();
        }

        Iterator it = enc.getEncryptedDataObjects();
        PGPPrivateKey sKey = null;
        PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData pbe = null;
        PGPSecretKeyRingCollection pgpSec = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(keyIn), new JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator());

        while (sKey == null && it.hasNext()) {
            pbe = (PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData) it.next();

            sKey = findSecretKey(pgpSec, pbe.getKeyID(), passwd);
        }

        if (sKey == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("secret key for message not found.");
        }

        InputStream clear = pbe.getDataStream(new JcePublicKeyDataDecryptorFactoryBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(sKey));

        JcaPGPObjectFactory plainFact = new JcaPGPObjectFactory(clear);

        PGPCompressedData cData = (PGPCompressedData) plainFact.nextObject();

        InputStream compressedStream = new BufferedInputStream(cData.getDataStream());
        JcaPGPObjectFactory pgpFact = new JcaPGPObjectFactory(compressedStream);

        Object message = pgpFact.nextObject();

        if (message instanceof PGPLiteralData) {
            PGPLiteralData ld = (PGPLiteralData) message;

            String outFileName = ld.getFileName();
            //if (outFileName.length() == 0) {
                outFileName = defaultFileName;
            //}

            InputStream unc = ld.getInputStream();
            OutputStream fOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFileName));

            Streams.pipeAll(unc, fOut);

            fOut.close();
        } else if (message instanceof PGPOnePassSignatureList) {
            throw new PGPException("encrypted message contains a signed message - not literal data.");
        } else {
            throw new PGPException("message is not a simple encrypted file - type unknown.");
        }

        if (pbe.isIntegrityProtected()) {
            if (!pbe.verify()) {
                System.err.println("message failed integrity check");
            } else {
                System.err.println("message integrity check passed");
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("no message integrity check");
        }
    } catch (PGPException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        if (e.getUnderlyingException() != null) {
            e.getUnderlyingException().printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The encryption is block-based and chained and appending is not chaining I guess. I'm surprised GPG is not complaining about the second data-chunk... incremental encryption as such isn't a thing. if you want to encrypt both lines separately then you will have to call decrypt twice afterwards, once per encryption.

Comment: How do you decrypt the data/file with GPG exactly? Please [edit] your question to include the commands you used to decrypt the data and the output you get. If necessary use the `-v` flag for detailed information about the decryption process. Also, do you plan to decrypt it in your code as well? If so, please include the code how you decrypt it and the errors/problems you get.

Comment: @Pagman, As requested I have attached decrypt code. saberobserver, Is it possible to encrypt the data  one by one using pgp. As per my requirement, I cann't do the encryption once as I am getting outOfmemory error.

Comment: @Pagman, I am decrypting only to cross check. My problem is I am having 4 gb data to encrypt using pgp. But Using java stream object I am able to encrypt with upto 2gb data.After 2gb I am getting OutOfmemory exception. So I want to split the process. Using chunk by chunk I am able to encrypt full 4 GB data. But while decrypting I am getting only 1st 2 GB data. Could you please how to resolve this data loss. Might be they adding some length in header for that reason I am decrypt only the 1st encyption data